# How to cache JQUERY GET response (data) and use it in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have following table in my database:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fullname  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| birthdate | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I query the data from same via following ajax method:

```
function getUserDB(){
    return ($.ajax({
        url: 'services/users?',
        method: 'get',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }, 
        success: function(data) {
                console.log ("getUserDB got the user data");
                UserDB = JSON.stringify(data);
                UserDBObj = JSON.parse(UserDB);
            }
    }));
}
```

I have an HTML page which should display the `fullname` at various places (divs) depending on the `id`. 
In order to avoid firing the jQuery for each `div`, I thought I can store the response on page load and use another method to get the `fullname`.
Here is what I wrote:

```
function getUserName(ID){
    var username;
    console.log(" getUserName called");
    for(var index in UserDBObj){
        if (UserDBObj[index] == ID)
        {
            username = UserDBObj[index].fullname;
            console.log("Got username : "+ username);
        }
     }
    return username;
}
```

I call `getUserName(id)` for the respective div where the name has to be shown.
However this is not working because the ajax call is asynchronous and `getUserName(id)` is getting called even before the data is acquired.

Any suggestion how to achieve this? I have seen similar questions but none of them appeared conclusive.

Comment: Call getUserName(id) in the success call back after you have received your data.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? `id` is dynamic and I need to call it with different values.

Comment: how you are calling `getUserName(id)`. Can you show us that code?

Answer (score 1):

try calling the function after ajax call is completed

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'services/users?',
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }, 
    success: function(data) {
        console.log ("getUserDB got the user data");
            UserDB = JSON.stringify(data);
            UserDBObj = JSON.parse(UserDB);
        }

}),getUserName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises (Deferred objects in jQuery environments) are the nicest way of dealing with requirements like this. It lets you deal with your async calls in a manner which lets you ignore the specific timing of your xhr calls. In the code below, your ajax call only gets called once, and from then on, whenever you call the `getUser` function, it just uses the cached results of the xhr call without repeating it. There is no need for you to track 'if ajax results are loaded' or anything like that.... the promise does that for you.

MDN on ES6 Promises spec:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

jQuery Deferred spec (same idea as Promises):
https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

```js
var xhrUsers = $.get('/api/users');

function getUser(id) {
  return xhrUsers.then(function(usersList) {
    return usersList[id];
  });
}

function getUserFullName(id) {
  return xhrUsers.then(function(usersList) {
    return usersList[id].fullname;
  });
}


//example

getUser('bob').done(function(user) {
  //do something with user bob
});

getUserFullName('jane').done(function(fullname) {
  console.log('user jane\'s full name is: ' + fullname);
});
```

Comment: Very good. Yes, promises are doing exactly the same thing, I wanted to outline with my answer, but in a much more elegant way. The only thing is, that they are a little weird in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your data handling routine once it has been loaded.

Something like this (you will have to replace 'myDivSelector'):

```
function populateUsers() {
    $(myDivSelector).each(function () {
        var name = getUserName(this.id);
        //handle user name
    });
}
function getUserDB(){
    return ($.ajax({
        url: 'services/users?',
        method: 'get',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log ("getUserDB got the user data");
            UserDB = JSON.stringify(data);
            UserDBObj = JSON.parse(UserDB);
            populateUsers();
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you basically can do (not changing the general behavior of your application), is make the getUserName function also asynchronous, since it is depending on a asynchronous event.

One possibility to to that, could look this way:

(I give only an outline, not the complete code)

```
function setUsername(ID, divId) {
   if (UserDBObj_isLoaded) {
      // do as before
   }
   else {
      // set callback function that will be called from the
      // ajax-call success handler
      var cb = function() {
         // get the value for the name
         ...
         // set the name into the divId
         ...
      }
      UserObj_cbs.push(cb);
   }
}
```

Here an outline of the success handler only:

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log ("getUserDB got the user data");
            UserDB = JSON.stringify(data);
            UserDBObj = JSON.parse(UserDB);
            UserDBObj_isLoaded = true;

            // process all the callback functions till now
            for (i=0; i<UserDBObj_cbs.length; i++) {
                UserDbObj_cbs[i]();
            }
        }
```